# Share ionic 4 / angular7 modules across projects

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have an ionic4/angular7 project with several modules. Now I want to make a clone of this project, using the modules as shared modules in every clone.

Structure:

```
folder
  |-- shared-module-1
       |--  index.ts
       |--  package.json
       |--  pages
            |--  myPage
       ...stuff

  |-- shared-module-2
       ...stuff

  |-- ionic-project
      |--  package.json
      |--  angular.json
      |--  tsconfig.json
      ...stuff

  |-- ionic-project-clone
  etc
```

I specified to load the shared modules in tsconfig

```
"paths": {
    "@sharedModule1": [
       "../shared-module-1"
    ]
 }
```

following this [tutorial](https://coding4dummies.net/sharing-local-angular-libraries-without-npm-99987470834c). The typescript compiler in VS Code works fine and I can run ionic serve without a problem. However in the browser I get an error like `Cannot find module './pages/my-page/myPage.module'`. Whilst the page is part of the shared module and lazy loaded (if that is of importance).

My guess is, webpack does not compile the page in my shared module. I tried messing around with lazyModules in the angular.json file, but so far no luck.

Has anyone done something similar before?

UPDATE:
I think it must have something to do with lazy loading the page inside the shared module. The shared module gets loaded actually I could see in the console. Just the page-module inside fails to load.

UPDATE 2:
I tried the same with symlinks, but ended up in the same error.

Comment: take a loot at this
https://medium.com/@blewpri/sharing-logic-between-ionic2-apps-f06feaf51fad

Comment: @RezaRahmati
thanks for the hint, unfortunately I had several errors with npm link, probably while compiling the external module. I will keep trying